# I have nvidia driver 304, can I install instead nvidia-331?

Tags: xorg, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a computer in which there's Linux Mint 16 64Bit. Currently I have the nvidia-304 driver, exactly the 304.121 one. I've installed it thanks to the xorg-edgers PPA, because i don't have any driver in the "Additional Driver" tab. I've gone to the nvidia official website and I've seen that the recommended driver for my graphic card (Nvidia 610M) is 331.67, which can be installed with the nvidia-331 xorg package. I've also done

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

but I still have the 304.121.

Can I install the 331.67 ? If yes, do I just have to do

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-304
```

?

Answer (score 1):

If you install the `nvidia-331` package, the old one will be automatically deleted.
If your graphic card is ok with this version of drivers, so go ahead.

Comment: Hi rawkinks, i forgot to say that I've got an Hybrid PC (Intel graphic card + Nvidia graphic card) and I use bumblebee. When the  bumblebee-nvidia package installed as dependence the nvidia-current package, it installed in turn the nvidia-304 package-driver.
So it's ok to install nvidia-331, right?
Are these the steps?
    sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-settings-331